# Cancel all tasks except from one in redux saga

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-saga

i'm reading some advanced concepts from redux saga documentation but i'm having a question here. In the documentation with use the following code to dispatch all action that are existing in our code:

```
import { select, take } from 'redux-saga/effects'

function* watchAndLog() {
  while (true) {
    const action = yield take('*')
    const state = yield select()

    console.log('action', action)
    console.log('state after', state)
  }
}
```

With the wildcard * we taking all the action in our application. Is there a way to take all action expect from one or two specific action? I want to dispatch all the action expect from "LOGIN" and "LOGOUT" actions? Any ideas?

Comment: The title is a little bit misleading. You said you wanna "cancel" tasks? `take` is not running a saga. At the point of that `take` above you already have an action fired up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation on [take](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/):

> If it is a function, the action is matched if pattern(action) is true (e.g. take(action => action.entities) will match all actions having a (truthy) entitiesfield.)

So you can do something like:

```
function* watchAndLog() {
  while (true) {
    const action = take(action => ['LOGIN', 'LOGOUT'].indexOf(action.type) < 0);
    ...
  }
}
```